# Authentication window doesn't come up on the remote screen

Tags: xrdp, tightvncserver

I currently have Xrdp and TightVNC server installed on my ubuntu machine, but when I access it over remote desktop, the authentication window doesn't come up on the remote screen. It was coming up on the main screen, but no longer does.

I followed this guide (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305) to get remote desktop working, and I'm using Mate 1.8.

I also had the same problem with Linux Mint 17 as well.

Comment: Same problem here. Using Ububntu Studio 14.04 (XFCE)

Comment: I ended up switching to x2go instead of xrdp, and it appears to be less buggy and faster compared to xrdp.

Comment: yeah, so did I.